# heroku крашиться при запуск express api

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

Код app.js слишком простой

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
let port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) =>  {
    res.send("Hello world!")
})

app.listen(port, (req, res) =>   {

    console.log("OK");
})
```

Пушу heroku свой репитизорий

Heroku успешно запустил app.js и выдал консоль даже. Захожу на свою ссылку для получение хеллоу ворлда, сайт грузит долго, через несколько секунд выдает это:

```
2021-06-01T09:39:27.885036+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 2.0.7
2021-06-01T09:39:27.886271+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2021-06-01T09:39:27.887260+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
2021-06-01T09:39:27.887413+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
2021-06-01T09:39:27.888211+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node app.js localhost 8080`
2021-06-01T09:39:28.123712+00:00 app[web.1]: OK
2021-06-01T09:40:25.021936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-06-01T09:40:25.063031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-06-01T09:40:25.135322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-06-01T09:40:25.242244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-01T09:40:27.132985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nodeserver.herokuapp.com request_id=b305cb5b-b93c-4082-9bd7-3b93d4b1f250 fwd="148.232.252.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-01T09:40:28.176787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=nodeserver.herokuapp.com request_id=3501c44b-a637-4020-a14f-1189f550d764 fwd="148.232.252.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-01T09:40:28.514639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nodeserver.herokuapp.com request_id=a1cd16db-96d0-4e07-b4d1-91b8efbd6b20 fwd="148.232.252.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Раньше работал этот код, а прямо щас уже отказывается**

Comment: можете дать ссылку на репу? а вообще, мне кажется, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693371/4496422 объясняется ваша проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать
let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;